# Button with handler and bound tag attributes

Tags: jsviews

I want to define in a jsviews template a button that have both click handler and data bound property.

Assuming I have this data:

```
var data = {
    Enable : true,
    DisplayName : "foo",
    SomeData : 42
};
```

This helpers :

```
var handlers = {
    fooClicked : function(data, evt) {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
};
```

How to add a button in my template to plumb the event handler and the properties of the button ?

I tried :

- `<button data-link="{on ~onAvailabilityClick SomeData disabled:^{!Enable}}">
       {^{>DisplayName}}
  </button>`
- `<button data-link="{on ~onAvailabilityClick SomeData} disabled:^{!Enable}">
       {^{>DisplayName}}
  </button>`
- `{^{on ~onAvailabilityClick SomeData}}<button data-link="disabled:^{!Enable}">
       {^{>DisplayName}}
  </button>{{/on}}`

But none of these works (either template syntax error or incomplete button, like having no text, or no handler).

I'm using jsViews 0.98.4.

PS: I don't know if it matters, but actually, my template is fed within a for loop, for an deep object structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find documentation on setting multiple data-link bindings, and other related topics here:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#linked-elem-syntax@fullsyntax
- http://www.jsviews.com/#link-elemattribs
- http://www.jsviews.com/#link-tags
- http://www.jsviews.com/#link-events

In your case, you need to write

```
<button data-link="disabled{:!Enable} {on ~onAvailabilityClick SomeData}">
     {^{>DisplayName}}
</button>
```

or if you prefer:

```
<button
  data-link="disabled{:!Enable} {on ~onAvailabilityClick SomeData} {:DisplayName}">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it :

```
<button data-link="disabled{:!Enable} {on ~onAvailabilityClick SomeData}">
     {^{>DisplayName}}
</button>
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo or copy-paste error. Did you mean `="disabled{:!Enable} {on ...`?
I added an answer with corrected syntax and some links...